# Accessing files in iOS safely

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have created an app that uses propertylist serialization into a file. I am getting some reports from users that saved data is sometimes lost. Is there something wrong with code below?

Maybe if the file actually exist but is blocked and the `fileExistsAtPath:` returns `NO`, therefore it gets recreated?

```
NSString *rootPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
plistPath = [rootPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"BookmarkData.plist"];

if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:plistPath])
{
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:plistPath contents:nil attributes:nil];
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "blocked"?

Comment: Please update your question and show us how do you actually write the data.

Comment: Print the variables via NSLog() to check the result.

Comment: Do you seriously use `createFileAtPath:plistPath contents:nil`?

Answer (score 2):

You don't show **where** you invoke that code.  Without that, no way to tell for sure.

If you are doing so only on app termination, then that is likely the cause of intermittent data loss.   It is never guaranteed that your application will be terminated in any kind of a friendly, controlled, manner.   The user may force the termination, the device may reset, the app may crash, etc.etc.etc...

Answer (score 0):

Api's that check for the existence of files typically return a true or false. False usually means that the file is in-accessable not that it doesn't exist. So for example if the file existed on a file share but you had no read permission it would return false. It maybe the same if another thread or user had the file open already for example.

Obviously on iOS some of these reasons are unlikely but something similar could be occurring.